# Requests module, "Exception has occured:TypeError 'set' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-requests, typeerror, cisco

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to issue a POST request to a Cisco DNA sandbox API, using the requests Python module.

> `'set' object is not callable " TypeError in the following code`

*I am new to Python and the Devnet world so any help would be greatly appreciated!*

```py
auth_path = "........"

auth = {"user", "password"}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

auth_resp = requests.post(
    f"{api_path}/dna/system/api/v1/auth/token", auth=auth, headers=headers
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

`auth` needs to be a tuple, but you're using a set instead.

The line

```py
auth = {"user", "password"}
```

creates `auth` as a set.  To create `auth` as a tuple, use parentheses (`(...)`) instead of braces (`{...}`):

```py
auth = ("user", "password")
```